# How to run a spring boot app in intellij?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I want to run a demo spring boot app in intellij idea but i have the error:

`Error:(3, 32) java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist`

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>helloworld</name>
    <description>Hello World project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Did you import it as a maven project into IntelliJ?  Is IntelliJ able to _find_ the appropriate dependencies?

Comment: I enabled the automatic import in settings -> build, Execution, Deployment -> Maven -> Importing

Comment: That just means 'if I change POM file, update your downloaded versions accordingly'.  Unless IntelliJ is made _aware_ that the project is a maven one, it won't download those dependencies at all.  You can do this via File > New > Project from existing sources.  Then selecting the root folder of your project and clicking 'Maven' in the options list that appears afterwards.

Comment: That didn't work!!

Comment: but I have this i:Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.6.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.6.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 13

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to open the pom.xml and not the folder. IntelliJ will ask if you want to import as a project. Answer yes to this question. 
You can always right-click on the pom.xml and choose Maven->Reimport which will do the classpath for you automatically.

Then you go to the main class from the tree and right-click and choose Run. That should create a temporary configuration in your run configurations.

The rest you can find here:

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html

If you want to run as a maven project, go with this:

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html

If you want to run from terminal as java jar, when you have built your spring-boot-jar press CTRL+TAB+T (to activate terminal) and type in the terminal:
`java -jar target/yourjar.jar`

Comment: Hi @eigenfield, what didn't worked, can you share details? It might be different reason from the original post. In that case please ask another question.